# Difference between "open function" and "touch command" in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, file

What's the difference in the below two cases for file creation.

```
  open(DATA,">newfile.txt");       #1.using open function
  close(DATA);

  `touch newfile.txt`;             #2.using touch command
```

Which one better and fast?
Note: When both open function and touch command used in Perl scripts, and the consider its used for creating empty files.

Comment: Obviously the first one is more lightweight since it does not need to spawn an external touch process. Read: [backtic operator](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~spector/extension/perl/notes/node73.html)

Comment: The `touch` command gives access to [`utime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/utime.html), not `open`.

Comment: Tip: There's already a file handle named `DATA`. Use another name. In fact, use a lexical variable (`open my $fh, ...`) instead of a global one!

Comment: Re "*Which one better and fast?*", That question makes no sense. Those two things aren't equivalent, so you should be asking "which one of these does what I want?" The `open` will clobber the file if it exists, whereas `touch` will leave it untouched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clear difference is that in the second case you are going out to the system. A shell is started which runs the command or the command runs via `execvp` system call (depending on the arguments, see below). There is a lot going on, and a number of things can go wrong as well.

More importantly, there is really more to do.  What if the file already exists? For one thing, `open` will truncate it while `touch` will only update timestamps. But you want a *new* file, so you need to check first anyway. What if this fails?  You need to check. Thus this should be a little routine.

Then just write it all in Perl.  There is no advantage in delegating such a simple job, only pitfalls.

---

Note: use three-argument `open`

```
open my $fh, '>', $file  or ...
```

with all requisite checks.  Then you also have a much nicer *lexical (indirect) filehandle* to work with.

---

Thanks to [hek2mgi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) for comments and to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for clarifying that [qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) may bypass the shell depending on arguments (what appears undocumented?)<sup>†</sup>, much like [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) does.

This can be checked, per [hek2mgi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) comment, by `strace -f script.pl`, where with `qx(touch "NEW")` in the script we find the line

```
[pid 24332] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "touch \"NEWFILE\""], [/* ...
```

while there is no `/bin/sh` in the output  for `qx(touch NEW)` (no quotes, no shell).

To note, `qx` does accept an array (unmentioned in docs), which clearly gets interpolated.  This is seen from output of `strace -f` on `qx(@cmd)` with `@cmd = qw(ls -l > tt.out)`, which has

```
[pid 30773] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "ls -l > tt.out"], [/* ...
```

Then a shell runs if needed (this example) and not otherwise (`qw(ls -l`)), as discussed above.

---

<sup>†</sup> But at this point (Oct 2022) I do find it in `qx` docs, loud and clear and upfront

Comment: Basically correct. But perl is not starting a shell. perl clones itself and does execve touch itself, without a shell. I also had to realize that. Check strace.

Comment: @hek2mgl That's interesting! I will check -- the standard lore is that `qx` _does_ start a shell (`/bin/sh` or whatever is gets relegated to). For `system`, there is a `fork` and `exec` and If arguments come in a list then `execvp` is used.  Even with one item in a list this can be forced.  I am unsure now whether all this applies to `qx`

Comment: Actually the documentation you sent does not say that it launches the command in a shell. It just says that it launches the system command. But I admit that also expected a shell there. Even more interesting, as soon as you  run `touch file | cat` perl *will* start a shell! Looks like perl is analyzing the command line, playing a shell parser.

Comment: @hek2mgl  According to [`qx` in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators), the `qx` (backticks) just runs a shell, which is what I recall. With [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) it analyzes the  string. (I didn't send docs before?)  But I will look into it, thanks.

Comment: Oh right! I [googled](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_qx.htm) that myself. :) Sorry if I refer to 3rd party docs, I'm not a perl hacker. Anyhow, imo `strace -f perl test.pl` is pretty clear about that.

Comment: It's an optimization. If there are no special characters, Perl bypasses the shell. `touch foo` = no shell, `touch "foo"` = shell. Perl also bypasses the shell if the only special characters are `2>&1`.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, that's what it looks like. Thanks for the extra info.

Comment: @ikegami  For `qx` as well?  It's undocumented?

Comment: system/exec/readpipe(qx) all use the same guts (except on Windows) from the looks of it.

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you for that, added.  While I'd "expect" it I never saw it in documentation. Will look again.

Comment: @hek2mgl  Thank you for the comments. I adjusted the text.

Answer (score 4):

> *Which one better and fast?

That question makes no sense. The two snippets aren't equivalent, so you should be asking "which one of these does what I want?" The `open` will clobber the file if it exists, whereas `touch` will leave it untouched.

---

As for which is better between using the system call vs shelling out to run an external command, the answer is obvious if you don't leave out most of the code from the question!

Using system call directly:

```
utime(undef, undef, $qfn)
    or die("Can't touch \"$qfn\": $!\n");
```

Using system call via an external command:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote("touch", "--", $qfn);
my $output = `$cmd 2>&1`;
die("Can't touch \"$qfn\": Killed by signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
die("Can't touch \"$qfn\": Exited with error ".($? >> 8).": $output" if $? >> 8;
```

As you can see, shelling out is far more complicated and error prone. And of course, it's far slower to launch whole programs to make a system call instead of just making the system call.

Answer (score 1):

They are two very different commands.

`touch` is used to modify the access and modification times of a file. By default, it set the access and modification times to the current time, and if the file doesn't exist - it will create it as an empty file.

`open` is for opening files for reading or writing. Depending on the mode given, the open command can also create a file if it doesn't exist.

To use `touch` means to invoke a separate process (a shell), so given that restriction, the `open` API command is preferred.

Comment: I know, I wrote that it does; but this is a _side effect_ and can be overridden.

Answer (score -1):

`open`  : used for read/write.

`touch` : used for updating/modifying.

But, `touch` opens a shell by actually cloning itself (perl cloning) for running another process.

Answer (score -2):

Open function is used to read/write to a file. The function uses a file descriptor and then write to the file specified. Whereas the touch function creates a new file.

Comment: The purpose of the touch command is to change file timestamps "update the access and modification times" of files (by default to "now", but this is configurable).
Creating the file is a side effect. RT(friendly)M pages for touch(1) and File::Touch.
File::Touch source checks for -e $file, if $file exists, update its atime and mtime, if $file doesn't exist, create it with sysopen. The open function also creates a file if it's used in write or append modes and the file doesn't already exist. I have seen people use touch to create files before they write to them - this is unnecessary.