# Perl backticks using bash

Tags: bash, perl, backticks

In Perl, the default shell to execute backticks is sh. I'd like to switch to use bash for its richer syntax. So far I found that the suggested solution is

```
`bash -c \"echo a b\"`
```

The apparent drawback is that the escaped double quotes, which means I will have difficulty to use double quotes in my bash args. For example, if I wanted to run commands requiring double quotes in bash

```
echo "a'b"
```

The above method will be very awkward.

Perl's system() call has a solution for this problem: to use ARRAY args,

```
system("bash", "-c", qq(echo "a'b"));
```

This keeps my original bash command unmodified, and almost always.

I'd like to use ARRAY args in backticks too. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you think you need to escape the double quotes inside a backtick string? There are also lots of different ways to quote strings in Perl. Lastly, when you are trying to change shell from inside Perl to execute richer commands outside Perl, from inside Perl... well, maybe you should just use Perl? What are these commands that you need to use bash to execute?

Comment: One reason is that try to honor bash's syntax as much as possible. One application is to parse a string like it was a bash command. The script will take some user's bash  command because Bash is better known to users than Perl is. From a Perl dev's perspective, you are right. From a user's perspective, bash is easier than Perl.

Comment: If your users are so bad with Perl, why do they use it? Messing around with shells, escaping, quoting, keeping track of interpolation, error handling is potentially a LOT harder than just learning some simple Perl code. For example, you use `echo $BASH_VERSION` as a way to get that string into a variable, when in Perl it is just `$ENV{BASH_VERSION}`. `"abcde" =~ bcd` is almost exactly the same in Perl. None of your examples are easier in bash than Perl, and in fact are just more difficult and slower. It comes down to what exactly you are trying to do, which is why I asked.

Comment: Sorry, I may have confused you. I am the Perl developer. My users have basic bash knowledge. Therefore, my Perl script take bash-style instructions from users. I don't expect them to write perl script.

Comment: Allowing users to execute arbitrary commands on your system? Sounds dangerous. Well, best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) is a very nice option: as the SYNOPSIS shows, you can do

```perl
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';
my ($output, $error_output, $exit_code) = capture {
    system(@whatever);
};
```

as well as using system inside `capture_stdout` if you want the simpler behavior of backticks.

Plus it's very general-purpose, working on Perl code (even Perl code that does weird stuff) as well as external programs, so it's a good thing to have in your toolbox.

Comment: Wow, this seems to be it. And it seems to be part of the core. It took care the stderr and exit code too. I think I saw it during perl installation or somewhere.

Comment: I fed the command with array @whatever = ('bash', '-c', q(a=1 b="has spaces" c='also has spaces' d=$HOME e=`date +%H:%M:%S`));. It passed all tests. Thanks a lot

Comment: also tested @whatever = ('bash', '-c', q(echo "a'b")); worked too

Comment: @oldpride it's not core, but it's pure-perl, has no non-core dependencies, and works back to 5.6 (though you need 5.8.1 for sanity).

Comment: this is important to know as most Linux systems inside company don't have non-core installed. It hits my job site too. So for portability, I have to use "require Capture::Tiny" instead of "use Capture::Tiny", but then "require" triggers error:  Can't use string ("0") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Capture/Tiny.pm line 382

Comment: @oldpride no, it doesn't work that way. You use `use` whether it's core or not.

Answer (score 4):

For one, one *can* submit a list to `qx`; it gets interpolated into a string and then passed to either `execvp` or a shell (see [qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qx/STRING/), and the second part of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45273200/4653379) and comments). And if you *need* a shell then presumably that string contains shell metacharacters so it goes via shell.

```
my @cmd = qw(ls -l "dir with spaces");
#my @cmd = qw(ls -l "dir with spaces" > outfile);
my @out = qx(@cmd);
print for @out;
```

I make a `"dir with spaces"` directory with a file in it to test.  (For a command with quotes in it a shell does get used.)

Next, I would in principle recommend a module to compose those shell commands, instead of going through a nail-biter to correctly escape and pass it all, like [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote)

```
use String::ShellQuote qw(shell_quote); 

my @cmd = ('ls', '-l', q(dir with spaces)); 

my $quoted = shell_quote(@cmd);; 
my @out = qx($quoted); 
#my @out = qx($quoted > outfile); 
print for @out;
```

I use the `q(...)` operator form of single quotes to demonstrate another way (also useful for including single quotes); it is not necessary for this simple example. One still need be careful with details; that's in the nature of using complex external commands and *cannot* be fully avoided by any approach or tool.

As for running `bash`, note that normally `sh` delegates to a default-of-sorts shell on your system, and on many systems it is `bash` that is used. But if it isn't on yours, one way to use `bash -c` in the command would be to first prepare the command and then add that to the `qx` string

```
my @cmd = ('ls', '-l', q(dir with spaces)); 
my $quoted = shell_quote(@cmd); 
my @out = qx(bash -c "$quoted"); 
#my @out = qx(bash -c "$quoted" > outfile); 
print for @out;
```

A couple more notes I'd like to offer:

- That `qx` is an ancient demon. How about using modern tools/modules for running external commands?  There may be a little more to do in order to prepare your involved bash strings but then everything else will be better.  Options abound. For example

  - [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple) with its few utility functions
  - Use [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) to wrap a `system` call with syntax you prefer
  - The [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) can do any and all of this and then way way more
- Why use external commands, with Perl's (far) superior richness?  It's a whole, very complete, programming language, vs. the command-interpreter with some programming capabilities.  If you need shell's capabilities why not run just those things via the shell and do all else in Perl?

Comment: I saw that you had listed the three modules I suggested only after posting them. (I had only looked at the first paragraph before posting.) +1

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for saying that -- but it's good to show them nicely like you do (+1), instead of one having to wade through this long and chatty post for a mere mention

Answer (score 2):

I have the following sub that works

```
    sub bash_output {
       my ($cmd) = @_; 
    
       open my $ifh, "-|", "bash", "-c", $cmd or die "cannot open file handler: $!";
    
       my $output = ""; 
       while (<$ifh>) {
          $output .= $_; 
       }   
    
       close $ifh;
    
       return $output;
    }

    print "test bash_output()\n";

    my @strings = (
         qq(echo "a'b"),
         'echo $BASH_VERSION',
         '[[ "abcde" =~ bcd ]] && echo matched',
         'i=1; ((i++)); echo $i',
   );

   for my $s (@strings) {
         print "bash_output($s) = ", bash_output($s), "\n";
   }
```

The output is

```
bash_output(echo "a'b") = a'b

bash_output(echo $BASH_VERSION) = 4.4.20(1)-release

bash_output([[ "abcde" =~ bcd ]] && echo matched) = matched

bash_output(i=1; ((i++)); echo $i) = 2
```

My answer is long-winded but it fills my need. I was hoping Perl has a built-in solution just like how it handles system() call and I am still hoping.

Comment: one problem with this sub is that I am not sure it will pass on the $? in case the command failed.

Comment: it's a common idiom to replace your `my $output = ""; while (<$ifh>) { $output .= $_ }` with `my $output = do { local $/; <$ifh> };`

Comment: I would agree with you and gave you thumbs up,  but my code is definitely more readable. I remember the day I came back from being a python programmer to being a perl programmer again, how hard it was to recall what those idioms meant. lol

Comment: Here's a variation then (can't resist): `my $output = join '', <$ifh>;`  All one need remember is that `<>` is context sensitive (so when feeding `join`, which takes a list, it returns all lines).  But I don't have a problem with your way, it is crystal clear to anyone :)

Comment: this is better.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```perl
my @cmd = ( "bash", "-c", qq(echo "a'b") );
```

You can use any of the following:

```perl
use Shell::Quote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote( @cmd );
my $output = `$cmd`;
die "Can't spawn child: $!\n"                    if $? == -1;
die "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
die "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"  if $? >> 8;
```

or

```perl
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my $output = capturex( @cmd );
```

or

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run \@cmd, '>', \my $output;
die "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
die "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n"  if $? >> 8;
```

Comment: You can also use `open( my $pipe, "-|" )` plus `exec`, but the required error checking becomes extensive. You can look at the source of IPC::System::Simple's `capturex` if you want to see how this is done.

Comment: Unlike the first, the last two solutions are portable (for a command that's appropriate to the system). Unlike the first, they also avoid invoking `sh` to launch `bash` on unixy systems. (No idea what happens internally on Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes as delimiter with `qx` like this:

```
my $out = qx'bash -c "echo a b"';
```

this will according to [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop) protect the command from Perl's double-quote interpolation.

Unfortunately, this does not work for single quotes. If you want to do `echo "'"` for example, you need the following:

```
my $out = `bash -c \"echo \\\"'\\\"\"`;
```

**Edit**:

To help you managing the escaping of quotes you could use a helper function like this:

```
use experimental qw(signatures);
sub bash_backticks($code) {
    $code =~ s/'/'"'"'/g;
    `bash -c '$code'`
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it doesn't work for this: echo "a'b"

Comment: Yes you are right it does not work for single quotes.. That's a pity. It seems if you need single quotes you need to go back to backticks and escaping

Comment: Single quotes in a shell command can be escaped by replacing them with `'\''` or `'"'"'`.

Comment: Single quotes in Perl string literal (incl a `qx` literal) can be escaped by replacing them with `\x27`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shell used by perl :

```
$ENV{PERL5SHELL} = "bash";
my $out = qx{echo "Hello ' world from bash \$BASH_VERSION"};
print($out);
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55010798/2173773. Unfortunately `PERL5SHELL` only works on Windows?

Comment: @hakon, correct, it doesn't seem to work on my ubuntu linux. I tried to set PERL5SHELL both inside and outside the test perl script. The $BASH_VERSION wasn't printed out